# Need to get the last 10 users active in topic

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct

I want to get the last 10 user who posted a comment in a topic.

It doesn't work as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p.author, a.name
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users a 
ON a.id = p.author 
AND topicId =  ? 
ORDER BY p.id 
DESC LIMIT 10'


SELECT p.author, a.name
FROM posts.p
INNER JOIN users a
ON a.id = p.author
AND topicId = ?
GROUP BY p.author
ORDER BY p.id
DESC LIMIT 10
```

This doesn't work. I tried group by combinated with an order by. But that doesn't work either.. Any suggestions?

The results don't match the id index.

Post table content looks like this:

```
POST 1 -> user 1
POST 2 -> user 2
POST 3 -> user 3
```

Results:

```
2,1 etc.
```

Wrong ordered.

Answer (score 0):

this should get you the top 10.

```
Select a.author, a.name 
from users a
inner join (select top 10 id from posts group by id order by id desc) as posts
on posts.id = a.author
where topicID = ?
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; but this isn't what i need. The last 10 users submitted a post to a specific topic.

Comment: i updated the answer. sorry there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT p.author, a.name
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     users a 
     ON a.id = p.author AND topicId =  ? 
GROUP BY p.author, a.name
ORDER BY max(p.id) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The main difference between this query and yours starts with the explicit aggregation.  The `order by` then  uses the `max(p.id)` for the sorting.  By using just `p.id`, MySQL chooses an arbitrary `id` from a matching row -- and presumably the wrong one for your purposes.

Comment: this returns the oldest poster an just a single row?^^